# How to change font size in a pickerview?

Tags: cocoa-touch, iphone-sdk-3.0, uipickerview, font-size

I'm fairly new to iPhone programming and am trying to implement a double-component PickerView. At this point the picker works fine in terms of taking user input, created with Interface Builder. However, I need to change the font size to accommodate the text length in each column. I very much would appreciate any link to a straightforward method to creating a multi-component picker with an adjustable font size. Seems like it is not possible if Interface Builder is used to create the picker. So far I have not found any code links that address this issue in detail.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to implement the delegate method...

`pickerView:viewForRow:forComponent:reusingView:`

... and then alter the font of the UI element inside the provided view. I think the default is a UILabel. Alternatively, you can provide your own custom view.